# ESLint indent error when using nested styled-components

Tags: javascript, eslint, styled-components

An `eslint` error occurred during `React` project using `styled-component` and `typescript`.

#### error

ESLint: Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6.(indent)

[image]

#### source

```
const InputField = styled.input<{ error?: boolean }>`
  ...
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: ${({ theme, error }) =>
      error ? theme.color.error : '#0d58ee'};
  }
`;
```

```
// .eslintrc.js

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'airbnb',
  ],
  overrides: [],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [
      'error',
      { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] },
    ],
    'import/extensions': [
      'error',
      'ignorePackages',
      { ts: 'never', tsx: 'never' },
    ],
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': [
      'error',
      {
        devDependencies: ['**/*.test.tsx'],
      },
    ],
    'react/function-component-definition': [
      'error',
      {
        namedComponents: 'arrow-function',
      },
    ],
    'arrow-body-style': ['error', 'as-needed'],
    'object-curly-newline': 'off',
    'lines-between-class-members': 'off',
    'react/jsx-wrap-multilines': 'off',
    'react/require-default-props': 'off',
    'implicit-arrow-linebreak': 'off',
    'no-confusing-arrow': 'off',
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['node_modules', 'webpack.config.js'],
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      typescript: {
        project: ['packages/admin/tsconfig.json'],
      },
    },
  },
};
```

#### Question

An indent error occurs while using the value passed as `props` from `styled-component`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue using `Linaria`. In my case a workaround was to pass an object of options with `ignoredNodes` array with `["ArrowFunctionExpression"]` value to the `indent` rule as the third parameter in `ESLint` config file.

This will ignore indentation checks for arrow function expressions.

```
// .eslintrc.js

rules: {
  // ...
  indent: ['error', 2, { 
    ignoredNodes: ['ArrowFunctionExpression'] 
  }]
},
```